# Vuejs splice multiple item from list

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple delete option in my app and it does delete items from database but the issue is in front-end. Somehow I can't splice right items from list

## Demo

[image: one]

As you can see I deleted items `2 and 3` but item `1` removed from list.

## Code

`commented`

```
toggleSelection(row) {
    const myIds = this.multipleSelection.map((row) => row.id);
    this.$confirm('This will permanently delete the items. Continue?', 'Warning', {
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        type: 'warning',
        center: true
    }).then(() => {
        axios.post('/api/wishlist/destroyMultiple/', {ids: myIds}).then((res) => {
            this.$message({
                showClose: true,
                type: 'success',
                message: res.data.success
            });
            this.wishlist.splice(this.wishlist.indexOf(row), 1)  // issue comes from here
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.$message({
                showClose: true,
                type: 'info',
                message: err
            });
        });
    }).catch(() => {
        this.$message({
            showClose: true,
            type: 'info',
            message: 'Delete canceled'
        });
    });
},
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the input value (`row`) of the `toggleSelection` function? a single row? or all selected rows? or what?

Comment: @MuhammadVakili `undefined`

Comment: @MuhammadVakili [source](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#multiple-select) of this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, It seems that you're trying to access the index of `undefined`  and splice it right here:

```
this.wishlist.splice(this.wishlist.indexOf(row), 1)
```

The code above will remove the last element of the array.
Let's try this one:

```
this.multipleSelection.forEach(x => this.wishlist.splice(this.wishlist.indexOf(x),1))
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: a is not defined`